# Blackberry OS 4.6 and 5.0

Tags: blackberry

What is difference between Blackberry OS 4.6 and 5.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's sort of a vague question.  From the developers side you can look at the differences between the [4.6 API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/index.html) and the [5.0 API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) yourself.  The major additions I noticed were the accelerometer classes and the ConnectionFactory.

From the user side you can google any number of articles on new features for 5.0.  Here are a couple I found: [BoyGeniusReports](http://www.bgr.com/2009/04/21/weve-got-the-goods-on-blackberry-os-50/), [PCMag](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2355169,00.asp).

If you tell us more about your application we might be able to tell you whether you'd likely need to use the 5.0 OS or not.

Comment: i have create App. using 5.0 OS,(this is informative and navigation base App.) now i want to use this App. for 4.6 OS. so What are the changes i have to do?

Comment: How would we know?  Take Spedge's suggestion and compile your code with the 4.6 JDK, fix whatever's broken.

Answer (score 2):

Two major differences that I've found are that SQLite does not work on anything below OS5.0 (though it only 75% works on OS5.0 anyway) and that BrowserField2 does not work in anything below OS5.

Really? Try to compile your code using a different JDK and see what happens :)